# Reading diacritics in R

Tags: r

I have imported several .txt files (texts written in Spanish) to RStudio using the following code:

```
content = readLines(paste("my_texts", "text1",sep = "/"))
```

However, when I read the texts in RStudio, they contain codes instead of diacritics. For example, I see the code <97> instead of an "ó" or the code <96> instead of an "ñ".

I have realized also that if the .txt file was originally written using a computer configured in Spanish, I don't see the codes but the actual diacritics. And if the texts were written using a a computer configured in English, then I do get the codes (even though when opening the .txt file on TextEdit I see the diacritics).

I don't know why R displays those symbols and what I can do to retain the diacritics I see in the original .txt files.

I read I could possibly solve this by changing the encoding to UTF-8, so I tried this:

```
content = readLines(paste("my_texts", "text1",sep = "/"), encoding = "UTF-8")
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas what those codes are and how to keep my diacritics?

Comment: Instead of `paste(a, b, sep = "/")`, use `file.path(a, b)`. — Regarding your question, I can’t find a common code page for Spanish where ñ would be mapped to code point 97 (either in hex or decimal). Do yo happen to know which code page that computer is using? (it’s definitely not a Unicode encoding.)

Comment: thanks, @KonradRudolph, but I still get the codes doing that...

Comment: I don't know how to get that information. I'm using a Macbook Air configured in Spanish-ISO. Although, as I mentioned, I'm only having issues with those files which were written in a different computer that uses English.

Comment: Ah, yes, obviously, that’s the MacRoman legacy encoding, how could I have missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out, you need to set the correct encoding. Unfortunately the text file was written using a legacy encoding rather than UTF-8 — namely, [MacRoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Latin_encoding). Ideally the application producing the file would *not* use this encoding, and Apple products by default no longer produce it.

But since this is what you’ve got, we have to deal with it, and we can. But unfortunately we need to go a detour because the `encoding` argument of `readLines` is a bit useless. Instead, we need to manually open a `file` connection:

```
con = file(file.path("my_texts", "text1"), encoding = "macintosh")
on.exit(close(con)) # Always make sure to close connections!
contents = readLines(con)
```

Do note that the encoding name “macintosh” is strictly speaking not portable, so this might not work on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! Just to clarify, is this problem related to the computer that was used to produce the English texts or the Spanish texts?

Comment: @aprendiz More to the software. Was the text file produced by a Microsoft Office for Mac application? These are known to use the obsolete encoding. By contrast, by default Apple’s own applications will generally create UTF-8 files.

Comment: The texts were written on an online platform (Moodle). Then, they were copy-pasted into TextEdit (Spanish computer) or Notepad (English computer) and some changes were made to the original texts. I just want to make sure what part of the process is problematic to avoid having this issue in the future.